# Installing TWRP on a Samsung device, no fastboot (using ADB or other ways)

Tags: adb, samsung, recovery-mode, fastboot, flashtool

My device (Samsung Galaxy S3 I9300) is not detected by `fastboot` in **Download Mode**, but it is detected properly by `adb`. I want to install TWRP as my device recovery. Is there any way to install it using `adb` instead of `fastboot`?

There is a question about the problem of detection of the device by `fastboot` on this site (which has no working answer yet). But my question is not how to solve that problem. If you like to answer that problem please see [this page](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97115/samsung-galaxy-s3-i9300-is-not-detected-by-fastboot-under-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Why is everyone, who tries to flash his Samsung phone, using `fastboot`? Samsung phones need *Odin* to flash recoveries or stock ROMs. Then it's also detected properly (make sure you have your recovery in either `.tar` or `.tar.md5` format or it won't work.

Comment: or Heimdall.....

Comment: @GiantTree Is there any Ubuntu version of Odin? I searched by Synaptic but not found it!

Comment: See samsung's comment or the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no fastboot mode on Samsung. You must use the ODIN mode, which is an alternative to fastboot. On Linux there is a client application called Heimdall which talks to phones via Odin mode. So the answer to your question is ODIN or Heimdall. ODIN is the proprietary Samsung PC application, Heimdall is multiplatform open source alternative.

Alternatively, if you are able to root your phone somehow, you can put TWRP (or any other recovery) on your phone by rewriting the recovery partition via shell but this can be tricky and I wouldn't recommend it unless you know exactly what you are doing or willing to risk bricking your phone. If interested, I can write a generic how-to too but I'd rather leave it to someone with more experience on that - I only did it like 5 times.

Comment: Heimdall has a short help description and no manual or documentation. Should I ask my question about Heimdall on this site?

Comment: ODIN on the other hand has no documentation whatsoever. Personally, I consider Heimdall docs good enough, ymmv. Go ahead and ask about Heimdall if you have any specific issue though. Also try searching for Heimdall tips on XDA beforehand so that your question isn't too generic.

Answer (score 0):

adb sees your device, so then you can just go from adb to fastboot:

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

Phone may ask if this is OK, voids warranty, blah blah

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
```

After flashing recovery, remove battery, then hold the appropriate button combination to boot into (new) recovery. Then reboot into system from the new recovery. Otherwise, unless we reboot into new recovery once, the boot snoopery may replace new recovery with old.