# Samsung's equivalent to Fastboot's Temporary Flash

Tags: samsung, fastboot, kernel, odin

Questions that address Samsung not having fastboot can be found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97115/samsung-galaxy-s3-i9300-is-not-detected-by-fastboot-under-ubuntu-14-04) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97180/installing-twrp-on-a-samsung-device-no-fastboot-using-adb-or-other-ways).

**My question:**

With fastboot you are able to use `fastboot boot boot.img` to temporarily boot your phone with a custom kernel, and upon reboot use the stock kernel. Is there an alternate to the above command for Samsung phones. Because with Odin, it overwrites the current kernel, so if the custom kernel doesn't work your left with a soft-bricked phone and have to re-flash stock firmware losing all your data.

Comment: And that's one big reason why you should have a custom recovery! :) You shouldn't even be flashing boot imgs with Odin if you ask me.

Comment: @AndyYan Pretty sure OP mean `fastboot boot bootable.img` and it's amazing... It's a way of booting something (a kernel, recovery, etc) one time without modifying anything. Wanna try this kernel without flashing it, no problem... How about fire up TWRP well leaving stock recovery on the device so we can still take an OTA? Sure, you can do that. Wanna see if that new hacked recovery you just compiled works? Oh, it doesn't, just hold power and it's gone. And no, there is no Odin equivalent because Samsung doesn't support fastboot.

Comment: @AndyYan Yea that is what I would be using if possible, their is TWRP for my device which works on Kit Kat, but not Lollipop. This is where I wanted to allow a custom kernel so I can get another attack vector to gain root, and then modify the necessary files. My device is considered a low activity device, therefor its left up to me to craft my own root. Odin/Heimdall is the only other way to flash to the device other then TWRP, which I mentioned doesn't work with the current version of my device

Comment: @acejavelin Yes you are correct, that is what I want to achieve. And as linked, I have mentioned about odin replacing fastboot

Comment: @acejavelin I'm only focusing on the latter part of the story. As for the former part, yes I don't think there's a Samsung equivalent.

Comment: I think fastboot is denied on Samsung devices by design, in the context of *Knox*.  Counter gets tripped when custom recovery or ROM replaces stock. If fastboot were allowed and one had unlocked bootloader (international versions), one could probably by pass Knox restrictions and say flash a custom recovery, which Samsung didn't want. Obviously, Samsung will not reason this in public forums. That's my guess @acejavelin,

Comment: @beeshyams The aforementioned links at the top of the post state that samsung switch fastboot for their download mode/Odin, the logical conclusion is becuse it adds extra security.

Comment: @Matt07211 : true, but my point (not well articulated) is that it is at the cost of choking functionality like fastboot

Comment: @beeshyams Yes i realized that and had mentioned that in my comment, do you happen to know if download mode has that temp functionality or do you believe that it was casted aside

Comment: AFAIK download mode never permitted what you are seeking. Can't quote a source but on the contrary won't find a source of way at XDA to say it is possible

Comment: Okay, thanks for that info, feel free to post it as answer and if possible quote a source ;) and reap the karma