# ADB does not reboot my Samsung Galaxy SIII I9300 to bootloader (download) mode

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-3, reboot, download-mode

My device is Samsung Galaxy S3 I9300 and I did a complete factory reset. The device is **NOT** rooted yet. It works properly. I can do all of the following with my device:

- Power off using device keys.
- Start in **recovery mode** and **download mode** using device keys.
- device is detected properly in **normal mode** and **recovery mode** by `adb` when is connected to PC through a USB cable
- I am able to reboot the device using `adb reboot` command
- `adb reboot recovery` works well.

The problem is that if I run `adb reboot bootloader` or `adb reboot-bootloader` commands, the device is booted in normal mode, NOT in **download mode**. The only way to reboot the device in **download mode** is to use the **Power + Volume Down + Home** keys

Comment: There is another problem with this device that my help to solve this problem. For more information please see this question: (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97115/samsung-galaxy-s3-i9300-is-not-detected-by-fastboot-under-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with Samsung devices this is not a bug but rather a feature. The "download" AKA "ODIN" mode on Samsung devices is a proprietary alternative to bootloader/fastboot mode and I don't remember being able to boot to this mode in other than the hardware way.

Answer (score 0):

The command below works for my s3.

`adb reboot download`

Comment: Could you provide the output of `adb help`? download option is not supported with reboot. See source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/refs/heads/master/commandline.cpp#192

Comment: As far as I know, `adb reboot` is shorthand that does the same thing as `/system/bin/reboot` binary, whose syntax is `usage: reboot [-p] [rebootcommand]`. From testing, reboot commands for Samsung-based devices are `recovery` and `download`. Samsung devices have a proprietary implementation of fastboot/bootloader mode called download mode, hence `download` option.